# Exercício de programação orientada a objetos em Python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Comecei a estudar a programação orientada a objetos em Python nesta semana e fiz um exercício mas não sei se ele está certo. Preciso que alguém dê uma olhada nele para apontar meus erros porque apesar do código estar funcionando, ele está diferente do que aparece no gabarito. Aqui está o exercício:

Classe Quadrado: Crie uma classe que modele um quadrado:

Atributos: Tamanho do lado

Métodos: Mudar valor do Lado, Retornar valor do Lado e calcular Área.

```
class Quadrado():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.tamanho_lado = x
    def mudar_val_lado(self, novo_lado):
        x = novo_lado
        self.tamanho_lado = novo_lado
    def retorna_val_lado(self, x):
        self.tamanho_lado = x
        print(x)
    def calc_area(self, x):
        self.tamanho_lado = x
        print(x*x)

carreau = Quadrado(5)
print(carreau.tamanho_lado)

carreau.mudar_val_lado(4)
print(carreau.tamanho_lado)

carreau.retorna_val_lado(3)

carreau.calc_area(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Por que todas os métodos recebem `x` e alteram a propriedade `tamanho_lado`? Se existe um método `mudar_val_lado`, todas as alterações deveriam ser feitas única e exclusivamente por ele

Uma função `retorna_val_lado` deveria retornar algo, não? O que for feito com o retorno deveria ficar fora da classe. O mesmo vale para `calc_area`. E se agora, além de fazer isso, você precisasse calcular a soma das áreas? Teria que ter um novo método que calculasse a área e depois somasse, se seu método só retornar o valor do cálculo, você pode fazer o que quiser com ele, não só *printar* na tela

Pode haver casos em que se quer fazer o que está fazendo, mas são raros e esse não parace um deles

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas. Tentei evitar os erros que foram apontados.

Answer (score -3):

```
class Quadrado():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.tamanho_lado = x

    def mudar_val_lado(self, novo_lado):
        x = novo_lado
        self.tamanho_lado = x

    def retorna_val_lado(self):
        print(self.tamanho_lado)

    def calc_area(self):
        self.tamanho_lado = self.tamanho_lado*self.tamanho_lado
        print(self.tamanho_lado)
```

Comment: Além de não explicado o que foi feito, este código não faz sentido. Por que `mudar_val_lado` define o valor de `x` para depois usar em `tamanho_lado`? Por que `retorna_val_lado` exibe o valor do lado ao invés de retorná-lo? Por que `calc_area` salva o valor da área em `self.tamanho_lado` e por que ele exibe o resultado ao invés de retorná-lo?